# How to transform a JavaScript ES6 class into a class-factory mixin at runtime?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I think this is fairly possible with ES5 classes, due to being able to easily use `Constructor.apply` or `Constructor.call` to run constructor logic on `this`, but I'm wondering if it is possible to convert an ES6+ (ES2015+) class into a class-factory mixin.

For example, suppose I have the following `Foo` class:

```js
// FooMixin.js

// Leave this class definition as is, this code should not be modified.
class Foo {
  foo = 1
}

// only modify starting here
export const FooMixin = // ... make FooMixin using the reference to Foo ...
```

so that the consumer code can do:

```js
import {FooMixin} from './FooMixin.js'

class Bar {
  bar = 2
}

const FooBar = FooMixin(Bar)

const fb = new FooBar
console.log(fb.foo, fb.bar) // 1 2
```

The goal is not to touch the `Foo` definition, but to make the mixin entirely after the definition of `Foo`.

I know that I can make the mixin the regular way, by wrapping it in a function, but that is not the requirement here. For example, I could write this:

```js
function FooMixin (Base) {
  return class Foo extends Base {
    foo = 1
  }
}
```

But that's not an option. I specifically would like to know if it can be achieved without modifying the definition of `Foo`.

For example, suppose I simply import `Foo`, and want to create a mixin out of it like this:

```js
// Foo.js
// This file should not be modified.
export class Foo {
  foo = 1
}
```

```js
// FooMixin.js

import {Foo} from './Foo.js' // import the Foo class untouched.

export const FooMixin = // ... generate FooMixin from Foo ...
```

Maybe I can use [`newless`](https://github.com/Mr0grog/newless), to make this work as described in the [`Caveats` section](https://github.com/Mr0grog/newless#caveats), by prototypically extending from the `this` returned by the ES6+ class (f.e. `Foo` in this example) in an internal wrapper "sub class" (f.e. inside of `FooMixin`). Maybe this is even the answer, if anything is possible at all, but I'm not entirely sure yet.

Comment: Yes, as documented on that `newless` page, it is not generally possible, and either `Foo` or `Bar` will no longer work completely like without the mixin. The easiest way is to simply instantiate both and copy over properties with `Object.assign`, making it relatively obvious what will be lost.

Comment: @Bergi That would lose all the methods, which may be desirable to keep. I suppose if `this` isn't the same this, but the end user doesn't know, it isn't a big deal. What matters is properties and methods work (excepting the case of name collisions, in which case some convention should exist. Maybe the FooMixin makes a new class, and lookups for properties from Foo or Bar happen with a Proxy (or accessors) on FooMixin's instances? This would also require `Symbol.hasInstance` code for instanceof to work.

Comment: @Bergi I'm wondering about this, because I'm curious if I can make a `@mixin` decorator to convert plain classes to mixins simply by sticking `@mixin` on top of the class definition.

Comment: @Bergi "Foo or Bar will no longer work completely like without the mixin" Can you list some things you imagine would be missing or go wrong? (I wanted to ask on ES Discuss, but figured I'd ask here first.)

Comment: The methods could be copied over as well, or even injected into the prototype chain (that we can do dynamically). The problem of `this` not being the same does matter a lot when the constructor closes over it (which includes arrow "methods"!) or relies on its identity somewhere. The user not knowing about this will cause great confusion, so you need to make it clear what is happening to `this` in your docs (like newless did).

Comment: I don't think a decorator has the power to change the constructor to no longer rely on `this`, but I don't know much about decorators.

Comment: I mean that it is impossible to run `new Foo` and `new Bar` and have the `this` keywords in the two constructors point to the exact same object (as you would expect from a mixin).

Comment: @Bergi True, but I think that detail can be hidden just like newless hides it. Gonna give it a try with Proxy...

Comment: @Bergi Oh wow, I just visualized how to convert them to mixins, using `Proxy`s, thanks to the `Proxy` traps having a `receiver` parameter, and the ability to replace the last prototype object in a given class's prototype chain with a Proxy-wrapped version that can forward `get` lookups onto other prototype chains depending on if the receiver is an instance of the mixin's internally-created `class`. However, instead of doing that, I made a `multiple` helper that I can use to mix `class`es like `class Foo extends multiple(SomeClass, UnrelatedClass, RandomOtherClass) {}`. I'll be back to post...

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found until now is this:

```js
class Foo {
  foo = 'foo'
  hello() {
    if (super.hello) super.hello()
    console.log('hello from foo')
  }
}

const FooMixin = (Superclass) => {
  return class extends Superclass {
    constructor(...args) {
      super(...args);
      const fooInstance = new Foo();
      Object.assign(this, fooInstance);
    }
  };
};
```

but it has limitations. if you do this:

```js
class Bar {
  bar = 'bar'
  hello() {
    if (super.hello) super.hello()
    console.log('hello from bar')
  }
}

const FooBar = FooMixin(Bar);
const fb = new FooBar();
console.log(fb.foo, fb.bar)
fb.hello()
```

it will print:

```bash
foo bar
hello from bar
```